# How to use xarray/dask/pandas/deepgraph for parallel pairwise correlation matrix in Python 3?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, correlation, dask, pairwise

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on `xarray`'s documentation: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html#automatic-parallelization

My ultimate goal is to get a pairwise spearman correlation matrix from a dataset that has ~100,000 attributes which led me to the tutorial mentioned above.  I'm testing implementations out on the `iris dataset` from `sklearn` but I'm having issues since this type of parallelization syntax is a lot different than that of `joblib`.

I can't figure out how to get the code below to make a pairwise spearman correlation matrix with a resulting shape of `(150,150)`.  I showed an example of doing it in `pandas` but this is not parallel and will take forever on my actual dataset.

**Does anyone know how to adapt this `xarray` code to work with creating symmetric correlation measures? If not, can someone direct me to a better method for doing pairwise similarity measures.  I'm aware of `sklearns pairwise_distance` but I'm wondering if that is the only implementation?**

```
import bottleneck
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

X_iris = pd.DataFrame(load_iris().data,
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])],
                       columns = [x.split(" (cm)")[0].replace(" ","_") for x in load_iris().feature_names])
da_iris = xr.DataArray(X_iris, dims=["samples", "attributes"])

def covariance_gufunc(x, y):
    return ((x - x.mean(axis=-1, keepdims=True))
            * (y - y.mean(axis=-1, keepdims=True))).mean(axis=-1)

def pearson_correlation_gufunc(x, y):
    return covariance_gufunc(x, y) / (x.std(axis=-1) * y.std(axis=-1))

def spearman_correlation_gufunc(x, y):
    x_ranks = bottleneck.rankdata(x, axis=-1)
    y_ranks = bottleneck.rankdata(y, axis=-1)
    return pearson_correlation_gufunc(x_ranks, y_ranks)

def spearman_correlation(x, y, dim):
    return xr.apply_ufunc(
        spearman_correlation_gufunc, x, y,
        input_core_dims=[[dim], [dim]],
        dask='parallelized',
        output_dtypes=[float])
```

[image]